# Prolog program firstlast without recursion?

Tags: prolog, append

How would I write a prolog program like the one below that succeeds if the list has the same first and last element but without recursion using the append predicate only?

```
firstlast([H,H]).
firstlast([F,_|T]) :- firstlast([F|T]).
```

Sample queries:

```
?- firstlast([1,2,3,1]).
Yes

?- firstlast([1,2,3]).
No
```

Comment: Hint: you can obtain the last element `Last` of a list with `append(_, [Last], L)`.

Comment: Furthermore I have the impression that your first attempt is not covering an edge-case: a singleton list.

Comment: Why without recursion?

Answer (score 0):

I think your predicate is missing an edge-case: the *singleton* list: in a list with exactly one elements, the first and last element are the same.

```
firstlast([_]).
firstlast([H,H]).
firstlast([F,_|T]) :- firstlast([F|T]).
```

You can use `append/3` to obtain the last element with:

```
last(L, Last) :-
    append(_, [Last], L).
```

This work since appending the `[Last]` to an certain list can only result in a list with `Last` as last element. Since that list is `L`, and `append/3` can work in that direction, we thus can obtain the last element. For example:

```
?- append(_, [Last], [1,4,2,5]).
Last = 5 ;
false.
```

I think with this hint, you should be able to solve the problem without recursion.

Comment: i am still very new to prolog. This is one of my very first programs and im still not too sure how to do it without recursion...?

Comment: @DovRoyal: you need to find out if the first, and last element are the same, so how do you do that? You obtain the first item, you obtain the *last* item (as demonstrated here), and then you check if the two are equal...

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a pre-defined Prolog predicate of some kind if you aren't going to use recursion. A simple solution could use `reverse/2`.

```
firstlast([H|T]) :- reverse([H|T], [H|_]).
```

This creates a nice, general solution:

```
| ?- first_last(L).

L = [_] ? ;

L = [A,A] ? ;

L = [A,_,A] ? ;

L = [A,_,_,A] ? ;

L = [A,_,_,_,A] ?
...
```

If you want to ensure that the list has at least two elements, then use an additional element:

```
firstlast([X,Y|T]) :- reverse([X,Y|T], [X|_]).
```

Yielding:

```
| ?- firstlast(L).

L = [A,A] ? ;

L = [A,_,A] ? ;

L = [A,_,_,A] ? ;

L = [A,_,_,_,A] ?
...
```